# Angular Preloading iframes to prevent delay during routing

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 11 application where I have 2 modules.
Each module has one component.
Each component contains an iframe to display.

Component A(template):

```
<iframe [src]="'/moduleA/index.html'"></iframe>
```

Component B(template):

```
<iframe [src]="'/moduleB/index.html'"></iframe>
```

Now in order to prevent the delay of rendering the components during navigation I have the following mechanism(preloadingStrategy) on the app-routing.ts.

```
const ROUTES: Routes = [
...
{
    path: 'web-app',
    component: DefaultComponent, canActivate: [ AuthGuard ],
    children: [
      { 
        path: 'moduleA', 
        loadChildren: () => import('./componentA.module').then(m => m.ComponentAModule),
        canActivate: [ AuthGuard ] 
      },
      { 
        path: 'moduleB', 
        loadChildren: () => import('./componentB.module').then(m => m.ComponentBModule),
        canActivate: [ AuthGuard ] 
      }
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, 
    { 
      preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules, 
      useHash: false
    }
  )],
  exports: [ 
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Providing this solution the iframes take 2-3 seconds to render. Is there any other way to render the iframes faster.
I suppose this delay is due to the destruction/construction of the components during navigation.

Thanks in advance